# REST URL best practice for id-related objects

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc

I have a class A which is related to a class B by a one-to-many relation (A can "have" several B )
But the only relation in the class code is that B contains the `id` of the A it is associated.

My url mapping for getting a resource of A class is classic, like:

```
/a/{aId}
```

I was just wondering what pattern is recommended for the url mapping of B class.

Something like this :

```
/a/{aId}/b/{bId}
```

which I currently have, because that way, I know by looking the url that the B object is related to the A object with the id `aId` but I now think this is useless because the B object already contains this id.

I'm using **SpringMVC** and **AngularJS** I need to put the `aId` parameter in the method and the calls even if I don't use it and it's a bit annoying.

Should I use the direct mapping instead ? like this :

```
/b/{bId}
```

What do you guys recommend and use in your apps ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of thinking how to map an URI to your class, I would advise you to think about how you want to expose your resource to your clients.

Meaning go for solution 1 (/a/{aId}/b....) if you want your clients to always use this path to retrieve/modify one or more "b" resources.

Go for solution 2 if it makes sense for them to directly retrieve/modify your resource b without passing resource "a".

You could even do both if there is a valid reason to do so.

Comment: Ok ! Thanks. I was thinking about the same thing. But doesn't it break the "convention" to use both ? I mean for example use /b/{bId} to get B, but use /a/{aId}/b/{bId} for posting new, since the url "root" is not the same anymore.

Comment: No, they have different meaning. Solution 1 provides "b"'s which are assigned to 1 "a". Whereas you could say that solution b will show you all "b"'s from all the "a"'s unless you provide a "bId". You are correct that you can get the same "b" using two routes though. But like I said, approach them as resources. Not as mappings of your object/data model.

Answer (score 0):

This is a decision you need to make on logical grounds.

I recommend you think about class A and class B as resources and ask the following question.

Does it make sense to have a B resource independent from an A resource?

If you answer yes to the question, then it logically makes sense to make B available outside the context of an A (`/b/{id}`). Otherwise, it makes more sense to make B available in context of an A (`/a/{id1}/b/{id2}`).